# How do I Respond to MySQL Workbench's "MySQL server has gone away"?

Tags: mysql, workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3 on both Mac OS X and Centos 7.  After a long period of inactivity, queries report "Error Code 2006: MySQL server has gone away"

I don't expect that leaving MySQL Workbench to maintain a connection to the server overnight, especially if I've let my computer go to sleep.

I *do* expect that there's a button or menu item somewhere that lets me reconnect again, WITHOUT having to copy the dozens or hundreds of lines of SQL I may have written in my current session.

I've been warned that I let my connection timeout, MySQL Workbench, now is there a way to please please just reconnect?

Answer (score 1):

Try Query -> Reconnect to server.

http://prntscr.com/auqdru